# Changing Pokemon to Pokémon

Tags: discussion, editing, pokemon

Many of my posts about Pokemon have been edited.

Is changing Pokemon to Pokémon really something best for this exchange?  It seems to make it harder for Googlers to find the answers to their questions organically.

Comment: Well, it is how it is spelled by the franchise....

Comment: As far as google's search algorithms are concerned, the two spellings are equivalent. [Example (Note the bold terms)](https://www.google.com/#q=pokemon)

Comment: I'd just like to point out that "Many of my posts about..." is a bit misleading, since you only have one post.

Comment: @RavenDreamer [Are they?](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10221029/arethey.PNG)

Comment: @3ventic Considering that link has the non accented versions bolded on my google search, I'm going to conclude yes, and maybe rant at google for being inconsistent.

Comment: @RavenDreamer We shall conclude that google is inconsistent.

Comment: Yeah, it stemms properly in Google. I still feel it's unnecessary to change it though. Most people without an accent on their keyboard will never bother to add it and 99+% of people reading won't care

Comment: If that's the only edit, it's too minor and should be rejected (or the editor should know better).

Comment: I'm now incredibly tempted to correct the missing accent in "posts about Pokemon".....

Comment: I'm with @MatthewRead - edits that consist of only a very minor correction (especially one that has no factual bearing on the post) should not be approved. We need to get out of the habit of approving things just because they're *not* wrong - edits should be substantial.  (I think in the particular example diras2 talks about in his answer, that the clarification was justified in that it was a little hard to parse before...but if the edit had only been to accent the e that would be pointless.)

Comment: Related: [Is an edit that only changes formatting, e.g. removing bold text and shortening link labels, too minor?](http://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7374/28182) & [Do typos or grammatical errors in titles warrant an edit more than ones in the body?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7741/28182), especially SevenSidedDie's answer on the latter.

Comment: Related [Search is too accent-sensitive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133336)

Comment: Thanks for the informative conversation and clarification on these issues.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As the editor in question: I edited the title, to clarify the distinction being made (instead of the oddly-emphasized [*GIVE*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/143613/1)). I only edited the occurrences of the word 'Pokemon' after deciding that the title could use the clarification and reformatting.